# How to center my logo on the page?

Tags: graphics, eso-pic

**What I want**

The logo (example-image-a) should be centered on the page.

**What I don't understand**

Can somebody explain me what the coordinates in `\put(100,100)` mean? Are this mm, em or px? I don't get it.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe} % example images

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\AddToShipoutPicture*
{%
\put(100,100) % the specific point of the page with coordinates (x=100, y=100)
 {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They are in terms of `\unitlength`, whose default value is 1pt.

Comment: @egreg: Is it possible to change the `\unitlength` to cm?

Comment: Yes, of course, but probably you want a different approach. Do you want centering with respect to the physical page?

Comment: @egreg: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The coordinates are multiples of `\unitlength`. However, for centering it's easier to use `picture`, that allows explicit lengths.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{picture} % explicit units in picture commands

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{%
  \put(.5\paperwidth,.5\paperheight)% center of the page 
    {\makebox(0,0){\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}}}%
}

\end{document}
```

With `\makebox(0,0)` the object is placed in a zero width and height box, with the reference point at the center of the object, so you don't even need to measure it.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Here is a method by centering with respect to the physical page, regardless what the margins etc. of the page are, with `Tikz` and its `positioning` library, applying the node `current page.center`, which does not need any reference to lengths etc.

With `opacity=` etc. it is possible to change the appearance of the image further.

The blue frame is just for marking the page boundary, as is the cross hair 'cursor' -- as can be seen from the screen shot, the image is centered perfectly.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\chapter{bla}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
  \draw[line width=2pt,blue] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    \draw[line width=2pt,blue] (current page.north) -- (current page.south) -| (current page.east) -- (current page.west); % Cross hair
  \node[draw,opacity=0.5] (A) at (current page.center)  {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
} 
\end{document}
```

[image]